# How do I make the Line in ChartJS not exceed the maximum of yAxes

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want the Line from this ChartJS not to exceed the maximum yAxes or in other words the line stays inside the element even though the datasets.data exceeds yAxes, i have searched the documentation myself but did not find it

**Like This**

[image]

**Not Like This**
[image]

**This my code**

```js
// Chartjs
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', "FRI", 'SAT'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Daily Data',
            data: [730000, 1012000, 1220000, 1831000, 560000, 2012000, 890000],
            borderColor: '#3f89fb',
            borderWidth: 3,
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        // X or Horizontal
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
          }
        }],
        // Y or Vertical
        yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero:true,
              max: 1000000,
              min: 0,
              stepSize: 200000,
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                return value / 1e6 + 'M';
              }
            },
            gridLines: {
                color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
            }
        }]
      },
      // Tooltips
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
            let datasetsData = chart.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
            if (datasetsData.toString().length <= 6) {
              return 'Income Rp. '+datasetsData.toLocaleString() + 'K';
            }else {
              return 'Income Rp. '+datasetsData.toLocaleString() + ' M';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Sorry i forgotten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code you can do something like:
Move your data to a var like

```
var myData = [730000, 1012000, 1220000, 1831000, 560000, 2012000, 890000];
```

Then change your data field to `data: myData,`
Then change your Ticks to

```
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true,
          max: Math.max.apply(Math, myData), //Sets the max to the max data you have
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 200000,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return value / 1e6 + 'M';
          }
        },
```

You can add something to the max to make it a bit bigger.

Comment: I think this is the same as my code and it doesn't work

Comment: As now look at your data - you have 2012000 and your max is 1000000 which is smaller - that's why.

Comment: Well, the problem is there i want the line still inside even though the data exceeds the maximum set (max: 1000000)

Comment: if you mean you want the data you have, that is bigger than you max to not be visible - don't think you can(or at least haven't seen such option)

Comment: I mean, values ​​that are greater than the maximum value will still be visible

Comment: Or if you mean you want your data to be visible in the graph - under the max even though its s numerically bigger than the max then you need to represent it in some way and mention it as a label - like dividing the data by 10, for example, and setting a label to point that it is 10 times bigger than shown, otherwise it is impossible.

Comment: that's what I want, thank you so much for helping me. I don't think of it